# How do I get my pandas dataframe to display the data in multiple columns across the page?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, display

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| year | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1950 | 7 |
| 1951 | 0 |
| 1952 | 0 |
| 1953 | 4 |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | 268 |

As the result is very long and not very wide, what I would like to do is repeat these columns across the page, so that the result looks something like this:

| year | number | year | number | year | number | year | number | year | number | year | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1950 | 7 | 1955 | 28 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1951 | 0 | 1956 | 12 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1952 | 0 | 1957 | 21 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1953 | 4 | 1958 | 42 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1954 | 14 | 1959 | 4 | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | 2017 | 268 |

I have looked at the documentation and can't find any way to do this. Is there a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this and see if it works:

```
groups = df.groupby(df.index // 5)  # Split the df every 5 rows

new_df = pd.DataFrame() # Create new df
for _, df_group in groups: # Iterate through the groups of the original df
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df.reset_index(drop=True), df_group.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) # concat the new df with the group
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of using groupby and placing into new df. I had to add dropna() into this code to remove the trailing values as the dataset wasn't exactly divisible by 5 but I have the result I want now.